# Having issue with delphi WSDL importer

Tags: delphi, wsdl, soap-client

I am importing a WSDL provided by third party.
but I am not successful with delphi WSDL importer.
When I import the WSDL then delphi WSDL importer is hiding the implementation of the classes from the WSDL file.The WSDL file contains some functions which accept objects as parameter.
After importing the WSDL delphi gives error as some variables are undeclared which are actually objects of class,whose definition is hidden by WSDL importer.

Comment: because the WSDL importer is not doing a very good job with the majority of web services, I highly recommend looking at other solutions(RemObjects, C#, Java to name a few). If you are going to push it, it won't be long until you start regreting the amount of work you will have to invest, in short, it would be easier to use TIdTCPClient to do raw communication with the web service server.

Comment: There is a [Free Pascal Web Services Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) for FPC, Lazarus and Delphi - maybe it works better with your third party WSDL file.

Comment: @mjn - that's new for me. Do you know about its quality?

Comment: Can you post the WSDL file here by chance?

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience with it, but the [Free Pascal Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit) seems to be in active development. It is compatible with Delphi,and can be used to create web service clients and servers.

It includes a WSDL importer, both as a command-line utility and a "Wizard". It also has a WSDL based type library editor.

The toolkit uses FPCUnit for test cases. For Delphi, DUnit is used.